# microservice architecure : a layer between service and its client

Tags: microservices

I'm quite a newbie to microservices architecture. I'm referring to one of my clients projects with microservice architecture. It has one of the service as Notification

```
Order ->(talks to)-> Notification client(as a lib) -> calls api from - > Notification service.
```

I don't really understand the purpose of having a client in between, where in it has a few exceptions handled for hitting the api. I understand, microservices communicate via api gateway but I feel Notification Client is just an addon. I tried to figure out the terminology used for this kind of implementation but in vain.

Please help me understand this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may feel that the client is redundant if `Order service` is the only microservice that is consuming the APIs. But considering the `notification service` is getting used by a few more microservices having a `notification client as a lib` makes sense. The reason is,

- The client lib will wrap all the API calls and their implementation
  so that other services can simply call it just like a method.
- Other services don't have to write REST client for notification service when it wants to
  make use of the APIs.
- Same client lib can be shared by other microservices without actually
  writing code to call the APIs.
- Any changes/fixes made to the notification service can be cascaded to other services by simply changing the version of the client lib.